# Propositional logic - how to simplify with 4 variables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm supposed to show that the following inference is correct. Excuse my English, is not my first language.

$$\ ((p\to q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)) \Rightarrow ( \lnot q \to s)$$

How do I use the laws and rules when I dont have anything that is the same? They all change to opposites when I simplify it, like $ \lnot $ before p. I have tried in many different ways.

I'm just in need of a clue so I can figure it out.
Thank you

I also wonder how I do when I have 3 variables inside one pair of parentheses. For example:

$$ (p \lor (p \land q \land \lnot r)) $$

I would guess its like this with the distributive law:

$$ (p \lor p) \land (p \lor q) \land (p \lor \lnot r) $$

Is this correct?

Im very thankful for any help, I have very limited possibilities to ask my teacher.

Comment: The question says it is true, I prefer to solve the questions without a truth table though

Comment: Karnaugh tables are for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, since we aren't working with numbers, $1$ will be used to indicate a true value, and $0$ to indicate a flase value.

Before I give you the answer, I'll need to introduce a lemma. The lema states that:

$\forall P\forall x\in\{0, 1\}(x \lor P(x)\iff x\lor P(0))$

We will accept the lemma to be true without proof.

Just kidding! To prove the lemma, first we will check if the lemma holds true when $x$ is true;

$1 \lor P(1)\iff 1\lor P(0)$

$\iff (1\iff 1)$, because $\forall x\in\{0,1\}(x\lor 1\iff 1)$

$\iff 1$

The lemma does indeed hold true for true values of x. Now let's check if it also holds true when x is false;

$0 \lor P(0)\iff 0\lor P(0)$

Trivially, the above is also true.

Now that we have proved the lemma, let's get back to the original question. Both of the "arrow" symbols in the question actually have the same meaning (let me know if that is not the case), so I'll be using them interchangibly.

$(p\implies q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \implies (\lnot q \implies s)$

$\iff (p\implies q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \implies \lnot\lnot q \lor s$, because $\forall x,y \in \{0, 1\}(x\implies y \iff \lnot x \lor y)$

$\iff (p\implies q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \implies q \lor s$, because $\forall x \in \{0, 1\}(\lnot\lnot x \iff x)$

$\iff \lnot((p\implies q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)) \lor q \lor s$, because $\forall x,y \in \{0, 1\}(x\implies y \iff \lnot x \lor y)$

$\iff \lnot((p\implies 0) \land (\lnot r \lor 0) \land (p \lor r)) \lor q \lor s$, because of the lemma

$\iff \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot r \land (p \lor r)) \lor q \lor s$

$\iff p \lor r \lor \lnot(p \lor r) \lor q \lor s$, because of De Morgan's laws

$\iff p \lor r \lor \lnot(0 \lor 0) \lor q \lor s$, because of the lemma

$\iff p \lor r \lor \lnot0 \lor q \lor s$

$\iff p \lor r \lor 1 \lor q \lor s$

$\iff 1$

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask me in the comments!

Edit:

In my answer, the precedence of logical operators is as follows;

1. Logical Not $\lnot$
2. Logical And $\land$
3. Logical Or $\lor$
4. Logical Implication $\implies$
5. Logical Equivalence $\iff$

When dealing with the same operator, operations are done from left to right, though this doesn't really matter because all mentioned dual operators (except for the implication) are associative.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat (p -> q) as one letter and evaluate each of the propositional logic. You can pick any order to evaluate them and if you have 3 variables inside a pair of parentheses you can evaluate any 2 of them in any order.

Comment: Thank you. I added an example, is that incorrect then?

Comment: But I also dont understand how treating p->q as one letter would help me in this situation, to use the rules to simplify it to not q -> s? I need it to be the same as one other variable to use the laws, I think?

Answer (score 0):

For $$((p\to q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)) \Rightarrow ( \lnot q \to s)$$ to be false requires $(p\to q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)$ to be true and $\lnot q \to s$ to be false.  For $\lnot q \to s$ to be false requires $q$ and $s$ to both be false.  Both $q$ and $s$ false turns
$$(p\to q) \land (\lnot r \lor s) \land (p \lor r)$$
into
$$\lnot p \land \lnot r \land (p \lor r)$$
which is not satisfiable.  Therefore....

Comment: Therefore the statement is true? Should I not break down the left side so its the same as the right?

Comment: @Sara Statements with free variables can be either always true, always false, or sometimes true/false.

Comment: Okay yes that i'm aware of, but I need to show that the left side -> right side. Isn't the best way to do that to simplify the left side so its equal to the right?

Comment: @Sara One thing can imply another without them being equal.  January implies winter is not equal to January.  And you don't need to *show* something, you need to *determine* something.

Comment: Okay. So even if the question states that "Show that the following statement is correct", it doesn't has to be equal? Its how the question is formed I take for granted that I should break down the left side so it is the same as the right?

Comment: No, you are not supposed to show both "sides" of the implication are equal.  And I meant to say "January implies winter" but "winter is not equal to January"

Comment: Okay thank you I've misunderstood it. Do you know how I can use rules when I have three terms inside paranntheses?